# Memory management in Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I'm doing some analysis on my Django database. I do many queries in a loop and some of these queries may return big results.
So, after a while the whole 8 GB of RAM on my EC2 instance is eaten and I cannot even ssh to the machine any longer.
I have to reboot the instance then start over again.

I tried the solution mentioned here:
https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/optimize-django-memory-usage/
But the `queryset_iterator` method seems not to work with aggregated queries.
I'm pretty sure that any single query cannot consume all 8 GB of RAM. So, this means that the old results are not deleted from memory.

How do I force a query out of the memory before the end of its loop iteration and before executing the next query?

Here is my code:

```
def get_users_event_distribution(monthYear, event_type=None):
    title = event_type if (event_type) else 'All'

    filename = 'charts/%s_%s_event_dist.png'%(monthYear, title)
    filename = filename.replace(' ', '')

    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print 'Chart already in file %s'%(filename)
    else:
        users = None
        if event_type:
                users = EVENT.objects.filter(time__month=monthYear.month, time__year=monthYear.year, event_type=event_type).values_list('user').annotate(count=Count('id'))
        else:
                users = EVENT.objects.filter(time__month=monthYear.month, time__year=monthYear.year).values_list('user').annotate(count=Count('id'))

        uc = users.count()
        print 'We have %d users'%(uc)

        print 'Building Count Dictionary'
        count_dict = dict()
        for u in users:
            try:
                count_dict[u[1]] += 1
            except:
                count_dict[u[1]] = 1
            count += 1

        print 'Built the count dictionary with %d keys'%(len(count_dict.keys()))

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
        bars = plt.bar(range(len(count_dict)), count_dict.values(),
                       align='edge')
        locs, labels = plt.xticks(range(len(count_dict)), count_dict.keys())
        ax.set_ylabel('# Users')
        ax.set_xlabel('# %s Events' % (title))
        ax.set_title('%s Event Distribution'%(title))
        ax.relim()
        # update ax.viewLim using the new dataLim
        ax.autoscale_view()

        def autolabel(rects):
            """
            Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
            """
            for rect in rects:
                height = rect.get_height()
                ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2., 1.05 * height,
                        '%d' % int(height),
                        ha='center', va='bottom')

        autolabel(bars)
        plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
        print 'saved the distribution chart to %s'%(filename)

def get_users_all_event_distribution(monthYear):
    get_users_event_distribution(monthYear)
    for event_type in [event_type[0] for event_type in EVENT_TYPE]:
        get_users_event_distribution(monthYear, transaction_type)
```

I run `get_users_all_event_distribution` for different dates in a loop.

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing some code.

Comment: Try the obvious first, set `DEBUG = False` in settings. If debug is enabled django will cache many things, including queries.

Comment: @DanielRoseman done

Comment: @BurhanKhalid didn't know that. I will try it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Well it didn't help. I noticed it went faster but still the memory kept filling up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more analysis, I found out that the problem was in matplot figures as stated here in this warning:

> /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:524:
>   RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created
>   through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained
>   until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control
>   this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
>   max_open_warning, RuntimeWarning)

I add the `plt.close('all')` line.